# Arithmetic operations in select with CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, select

I´m triying to do an arithmetic operation but i always get error. 
This is the query:

```
public function getAllModifiers($condition)
{ 
    $this->db->select('DM.id AS modifier_id, DM.name, minimum, maximum');
    $this->db->select('DMI.id AS item_id, DMI.name AS item_name, `DMI.price * 1.1` AS item_price');
    $this->db->from('dishes_modifiers DM');
    $this->db->join('dishes_modifiers_items DMI', 'DMI.modifier_id = DM.id', 'left');
    $this->db->where($condition);

    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

How can i get the item_price * 1.1? 
Thanks.

Comment: "i always get error"... what's the error?

Answer (score 0):

The backticks are used to escape object names (e.g., columns names). Any mathematical operation should be outside this escaping:

```
$this->db->select(`DMI.price` * 1.1 AS item_price');
# Here -----------^---------^
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.
Something like this?
$this->db->select('`DMI.price` *1.1 AS item_price');

That give me error anyway.

Comment: At the page i get a windows says: Internal server error. If remove "*1.1" work prefectly

Comment: You should attach your server log. Without it, it's basically guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

$this->db->where($condition);

This one not checking the data with the database values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in where condition

(DMI.price *1.1) > DMI.price *1.1